# ReactRouter blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After adding anything from react-router-dom the screen became blank.
I'm using react-router 6.3.0 and react 17.0.2.

Found a few solutions like adding to package.json the following:

```
"homepage": ".",
```

or

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
```

But nothing helps. I tried to find any issues in the code, by it's enough to add just anything from react-router-dom.

I tried the default examples from the official documentation, unsuccessfully.
Provided example bellow is just a default app with edited App.js file.

Here is an example that works:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const App = () => {
  return (
      
      <div>
        <p1>Test</p1>
      </div>
 
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this one does not work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const App = () => {
  return (
      
      <div>
        <p1>Test</p1>
        <Link />
      </div>
 
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thanks!

Comment: which version of react-router-dom are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code you are having an issue working with as a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As-is you've not provided enough context for anyone here to even guess as to why your app is rendering blank.

Answer (score 0):

if you have not wrapped your app with Router, you have to. Try doing that and also  takes "to" as a prop so you must provide that otherwise it will throw an error, and it should not be self closing.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Link to="/">
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

The issue was with the packages.
I have recreated the whole project and now it's working properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).